# Add a total column in an access transform statement

Tags: ms-access, pivot

I have the following statement

```
TRANSFORM Sum(revenue) AS sum_revenue 
SELECT year 
FROM revenues 
GROUP BY year
PIVOT month;
```

Which gives me a table like

```
year |    1 |    2 |    ...  |   11 |   12
------------------------------------------
2013 | 5000 | 6000 |    ...  | 5000 | 6000
2014 | 5000 | 6000 |    ...  | 5000 | 6000
2015 | 5000 | 6000 |    ...  | 5000 | 6000
```

I would like to add a total column at the end like this:

```
year |    1 |    2 |    ...  |   11 |   12 | total
--------------------------------------------------
2013 | 5000 | 6000 |    ...  | 5000 | 6000 | 75000
2014 | 5000 | 6000 |    ...  | 6000 | 6000 | 80000
2015 | 5000 | 6000 |    ...  | 6000 | 7000 | 85000
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had used the Query Wizard it should have built it for you by default, unless you have checked it not to include "Totals" column. However you can manually add it, by going to the design view and adding this,

```
TRANSFORM 
    Sum(revenue) AS sum_revenue 
SELECT 
    [year], 
    Sum(revenue) As [Total Of SumRevenue]
FROM 
    revenues 
GROUP BY 
    [year]
PIVOT 
    [month];
```

PS: I played with the query, I get the right result. Not sure why yours is not !

[image: Adding a Column as Totals]

Comment: Thanks, this is an legacy application I'm maintaining in Access 97, that's why there is not total.

Comment: I edited my question and your answer in a way that it will be more helpful for future visitors. I deleted my comments since they don't make sense anymore.